# Types and Programming Languages: What does Abb stand for?

Tags: ocaml, programming-languages, lambda-calculus, type-theory

In TAPL's example of fullsimple type. What does TmAbb stand for?

```
| TmVar(fi,n,_) ->
  (match getbinding fi ctx n with
      TmAbbBind(t,_) -> t 
    | _ -> raise NoRuleApplies)
```

Comment: By amusing coincidence, perhaps "type abbreviation"?

Answer (score 1):

Looking through the book, it appears that "Tm" stands for "term" but I don't see "Abb" anywhere.

However, I downloaded the code (fullsimple.tar.gz) and there is a constructor "TmAbbBind" just as you say. It's a kind of binding, not a kind of term. In particular it seems to be a binding for a term and an associated optional type that can be looked up by name.

So "term abbreviation binding" is what it stands for I guess. I.e., it's the thing that a term abbreviation is bound to.